# How to get exports form mdx in nextjs

Tags: next.js, mdxjs

## My Problem

The nextjs documentation on mdx states that it does not support frontmatter. Instead it is suggested to create a constant and export it [1]. However I can't seem to get at data exported in such a way. For instance using the following

```js
/* -- ./pages/example.mdx -- */
export const meta = {
    title: 'some example title'
}
```

```js
/* -- ./pages/index.js -- */
import Example from './example.mdx';

export default function Index ({ ... props }) {
   return <Example />
}
```

It seems that what gets imported can be used as a react component, but there does not seem to be a reference to the meta property anywhere.

- `Example` does not have a `meta` property
- `import { meta } from './example.mdx` does not yield anything
- There is no `meta` key on the rendered components
- Using `require ('./example.mdx')` yields the same results.

## What I wanted to do

I have a list of markdown files and want to create an overview page that lists all of them, using the metadata defined in every file. Something akin to the following

```js
import fs from 'fs/promises';
import path from 'path';

export async function getStaticProps () {
    const root = path.join (process.cwd (), 'pages/items');
    const listing = await fs.readdir(root);
    const items = listing
        .filter (item => item.endsWith ('.mdx'))
        .map (item => {
            const meta = require (`./items/${item}`).meta;
            const id = item.replace (/\.md$/, '');
            return { id, ... meta }
        });

    return { props: { items } };
}

export default function Overview ({ items, ... props }) {
    /* ... use items */
}
```

## Edit

It seems like there is a big difference between using `.md` and `.mdx`. In the examples I gave here I used `.mdx`, but locally I had used `.md`. Switching extensions makes everything work.

It is strange that the extension makes such a difference even though both of them are configured in `next.config.js`

```js
const withMDX = require ('@next/mdx') ({
    extension: /\.mdx?$/
});
module.exports = withMDX ({ /* ... */ });
```

[1] https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/using-mdx#frontmatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.mdx` extension instead of a `.md` extension.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can create a typing file to import it if you are using typescript

Step 1 - Create typing file

```
declare module '*.mdx' {
    export const meta: {
        title: string
    }
}
```

Step 2 - import the exported content

```
import Example, {meta} from './example.mdx';
```

Got the answer from here https://gist.github.com/peterblazejewicz/1ac0d99094d1886e7c9aee7e4faddef3#file-index-d-ts-L68